# In Crisis Mode, what do you do with cards that involve villains in your deck?

Tags: dc-comics-deck-building, dc-comics-deckbuilding-crisis

In the instruction book for Crisis Mode it says:

> - When you buy or gain a villain from the Line-Up, destroy it.
> - When you defeat a Super-Villain, remove it from the game.

What do you when you have a card that involves villains in your deck? For example, "Canary Cry" from *Heroes Unite*:

> You may put a Villain from your discard pile on top of your deck. If you choose not to, draw a card.
>
> **Defense:** You may discard this card to avoid an Attack. If you do, you may put a Villain with cost 7 or less from your discard pile into your hand or draw a card.

What do you do with that?

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen any FAQs or other rulings regarding cards that involve Villains while in Crisis Mode, so it looks like they do not behave any differently, aside from the fact that their Villain effects will never occur.

In the case of "Canary Cry", you are simply forced to always choose the option that does not involve a Villain card in your discard pile. If it helps, you can think of the card being rewritten like so:

> Draw a card.
>
> **Defense:** You may discard this card to avoid an Attack. If you do, draw a card.

Not nearly as powerful as the original form, but for what it's worth, there are other cards that are more powerful in Crisis Mode than in the regular game, so it balances out I suppose.